# Partial Canonical Correspondence Analysis in R

Tags: r, vegan

I am having issues with conducting a partial Canonical Correspondence Analysis (pCCA) in R. The data associated with code is quite extensive so I am unable to include it here.

The following code produces the error below it. In the pCCA model, I am attempting to account for both environmental and spatial variables in explaining species matrix. Spatial variables are Latitude and Longitude values. Env2 variables are a host of continuous and a few binary (0,1) environmental variables.

```
mod2 <-cca(species ~ env2 + spatial)
Error in model.frame.default(~env2 + spatial, na.action = na.pass, xlev = NULL) : invalid type (list) for variable 'env2'
```

I have used unlist () for both env2 and spatial, but it does not work.
Thoughts?

Comment: You don't need to provide your actual data, but if you want to know why your code isn't working, providing a toy example dataset that is representative of your actual data is a good way to get better answers, faster. It also makes your problem clearer for others who find your post and want to learn from it. See [mcve] for more.

Answer (score 2):

The right-hand side of formula must have *variables*, but it seems that you have data frames of several variables. This will not work, but gives a similar error message as in  your post (and this is documented). Further, your formula will not define *partial* CCA, because the formula does not contain function `Condition()` that defines the terms partialled out.

The formula interface may work if you have numerical matrices as terms, but it won't work with `unlist()` variables.

If you are using **vegan** 2.5-1 or newer, you can define a partial CCA *without* formula interface as

`cca(species, env2, spatial)`

and the data frames `env2` and `spatial` are automatically expanded to model matrices, and `spatial` terms are partialled out before analysing the effects of `env2` terms.